# Bootstrap container popout on hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row with 3 blocks within them (col-md-4) which on hover needs to "popout" (so it's edges will overlap the parent container). I have fiddled a bit but cannot figure out how to do this while still using bootstrap standard classes.

Any ideas on how to do this? Google unfortunately does not offer a lot when searching "popout containers" :)

Would prefer to do it in CSS

[image]

**HTML:**

```
 <section class='container-fluid whitebg center-align' id='whyus'>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 whyusblock">
                    <img src="/img/icons/highestgrade.png" />
                    <h4>LEADING INDUSTRY</h4>
                    <p>Our professional-grade tools, resins, and equipment are preferred by windshield repair and headlight restoration technicians and are respected for quality, durability, and ease of use.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 whyusblock">
                    <img src="/img/icons/highestgrade.png" />
                    <h4>QUALITY GUARANTEED</h4>
                    <p>Our windshield repair and headlight restoration products are used by technicians all around South Africa. Every systems comes with a 100% quality guarantee that won’t let you down.</p>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-md-4 whyusblock">
                     <img src="/img/icons/highestgrade.png" />
                    <h4>PROFESSIONAL TRAINING</h4>
                    <p>We provide free professional training with all our windshield repair and headlight restoration products, so you know you provide the best possible repair and restoration service.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**CSS:**

```
 #whyus {
     background: #f7f7f7;
 }

 .whyusblock {

  }

   .whyusblock:hover {
       background: #fff;
       -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.67);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.67);
       box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.67);
 }
```

Comment: I don't think you've tried hard enough. HAve you tried using CSS zoom on hover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/maky/4ckxpgzz/1/) with:

```
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
```

this will give you an idea how to fix your code.
Also you can check for some more examples in [here](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2014/05/8-simple-css3-transitions-that-will-wow-your-users/)..

Comment: I managed to get it working but then saw your answer and by far the best solution :) Answered!

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/fr243agf/

```
   .whyusblock:hover {
       background: #fff;
       -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.67);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.67);
       box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.67);
       transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
       transform: scale(1.1);
       z-index:9999;
 }
```